# 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Text'

Tags: c#

I know what a simple problem this is, but for the life of me I can't find the solution elsewhere. Here is my code:

```
int txtAge = 20;
txtAge.Text = txtAge.ToString();
```

The error occurs specifically for `.Text`. The TextBox object and the variable are both named `txtAge`. I know the reasonable thing to do is to give them different names, but this was done by my professor so I'm hesitant to change them.

Comment: If they are in the same scope then they must have different names

Comment: You've got to do what is right.. fight against all odds and change the name. Because it is the right thing to do. :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Hungarian notation went out of fashion a long time ago. Name things properly. Or if it's just that your professor set it as homework, then do some research. There's a 5 character solution to this.

Comment: The problem is that your local variable, `int txtAge` will be used by default before using the class member `TextBox txtAge` because of the scope of the variables. To force the compiler to use the `class` member, use `this.txtAge` (`this` represents the class itself). So you will end up with: `this.txtAge.Text = txtAge.ToString();`

Comment: while this is bad practice, the point your prof might be trying to make is you can get to the scope of the textBox through the use of `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `this` to tell the compiler you want to use the non-local variable:

```
this.txtAge.Text = txtAge.ToString();
```

- Also, note the `()` after `ToString`. You'll need those.

Also note that this practice is highly discouraged. You should avoid re-using variable names.